# LINKER error: comsupp.lib and comsuppwd.lib

Tags: c++, com, linker, c-strings, lnk2005

error is:

> Error 14  error LNK2005: "void __stdcall _set_com_error_handler(void (__stdcall*)(long,struct IErrorInfo *))" (?_set_com_error_handler@@YGXP6GXJPAUIErrorInfo@@@Z@Z) already defined in comsupp.lib(comsupp.obj)  comsuppwd.lib

Did anyone run into this before?

Comment: The declaration and definition signatures of a function must match. In your case, the definition doesn't change, so the linker can't find the function by its declaration signature.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko I modified both declaration and definition. I feel like the error has to do with my implementation inside my definitions.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look at the error text at first. Looks like some function is declared in multiple object files. It can happen if a function body is defined in a header file, for example.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko You're right. Error is about `comsupp.lib` and `comsuppwd.lib` I'm not sure how these libraries are involved.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko Problem is resolved now. It was due to a header file: `#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is resolved now. The cause of error was a header file: `#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>` and conversion from `System::String^` to `std::string`(I found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2654097/3405291)):

```
//commented out following 3 lines and problem solved:
//looks like following type conversion has problems:
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>
msclr::interop::marshal_context marshal_context_1;
string_TempDir_XMLfiles=marshal_context_1.marshal_as<std::string>(String_Ptr_Destin_Dir_XMLfiles);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the Visual Studio 2010 header  `<msclr/marshal.h>`.
There is written

```
#pragma comment(lib, "comsupp.lib")
```

but compared to `<comdef.h>` there must be written

```
#ifdef _NATIVE_WCHAR_T_DEFINED
# ifdef _DEBUG
# pragma comment(lib, "comsuppwd.lib")
# else
# pragma comment(lib, "comsuppw.lib")
# endif
#else
# ifdef _DEBUG
# pragma comment(lib, "comsuppd.lib")
# else
# pragma comment(lib, "comsupp.lib")
# endif
#endif
```

See also the Lib-section in https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/cpp/set-com-error-handler?view=vs-2019

So you have 2 Options

1. BAD: Edit the `msclr/marshal.h` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\msclr\marshal.h`. But then all collegues must change their file too.
2. Change the ProjectSetting `Linker` -> `Input` -> `Ignore Specific Default Libraries` and add `commsupp.lib`. !!!But attention if you have set the compiler option `/Zc: wchar_t-` (see `C/C++` -> `Language` -> `Treat WChar_t as Built in Type`)  AND compiling for Release then it must not be ignored!!! So each project configuration may/must be changed differently.